# How to get records using whereHas if child has no NULL value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using whereHas and I only want to return the records if sub query has no NULL

```
return App\Bill_of_Lading::with('transactions.confirmed_transaction.delivery_order')
    ->whereHas('transactions.confirmed_transaction.delivery_order', function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('date_delivered');
    })->get();
```

Expected result: NULL (because there are delivery orders that have NULL date_delivered)
Result: The collection of Bill of Ladings together with the delivery orders with NULL values

I also used Laravel's "with" with no success

```
return App\Bill_of_Lading::with(['transactions.confirmed_transaction.delivery_order' => function($query){
        $query->whereNotNull('date_delivered');
    }])->get();
```

I even wrapped the whereNotNull inside where

```
return App\Bill_of_Lading::with('transactions.confirmed_transaction.delivery_order')
    ->whereHas('transactions.confirmed_transaction.delivery_order', function ($query) {
        $query->where(function($q){
            $q->whereNotNull('date_delivered');
        });
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, `whereHas()` has extra parameters for the query conditions. So check if the relationship has null fields and assert it to be 0, therefor no delivery order columns can be null.

```
->whereHas(
    'transactions.confirmed_transaction.delivery_order', function ($query) {
        $query->whereNull('date_delivered');
    },
    '=',
    0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this @mrhn ! Just tried this but for some reason, I'm still having the same results :
The collection of Bill of Ladings together with the delivery orders with NULL values.

I'm quite confused now, cause I think this should solve my issue. I wonder what's the problem.

Comment: But when I try to make it: `'<', 0` it always return NULL.

Comment: but it should be '=', 0, is it the exact snippet you put in?

Comment: yes, I tried `'=', 0` and tested `'<', 0`. I'm having a hunch that this doesn't work because it's nested. I tried using the same logic with just the transactions and it worked fine.

Comment: when you run it with '=', 0, what is your result? what data is there etc.?

Comment: same as if I didn't put the extra parameters – Collection of Bill of Ladings together with the delivery orders with NULL values

Comment: I will try to create an local project and see if i can recreate if i'm not back within a week feel free to ping me to see how it is going :)

Comment: Thank you @mrhn ! You're very kind. Will keep this thread updated until I fixed this.